# Как убрать постоянный запрос пароля в Outlook к Exchange?

Tags: dns, outlook, exchange

Помогите пожалуйста.

Дан сервер exchange 13 в локальном домене.
Дана машина с outlook 13 в локальном домене.

При попытке подключится с аутлука к exchange постоянно говорит что пароль неверный. И не может подключиться. 
Знаю что мало информации. Но запрашивайте какую нужно.

Вопрос 2. Как посмотреть логи подключения клиентов к серверу exchange?

Comment: Это у вас какой-то глюк, либо в оутглюке что-то не так настроено. А пользователь, который входит в локальный компьютер, он доменный пользователь или локальный?

Comment: Доменный. Но у нас также есть внешний доступ. Он выдает тоже самое.

Comment: Я подзабыл всё довольно основательно, но кажется в виндовсе всё завязано на настройку почты или что-то в этом роде, доступно через панель управления. Там задаётся куча (по необходимости конечно) почтовых учётных записей. Может там что-то не так. В домене автоматически определяется exchange сервер и пользователь по крайней мере outlook-а никаких проблем не испытывают. outlook-же стандартный клиент exchang-а? Даже и это запамятовал.

Comment: Все верно. При первом входе в Outlook выскакивает окно с подключеннием к такому то серверу (автоматически) и запрашивает имя пользователя (пароль и имя по идее должен забирать из доменной записи под которой произведен вход был). Все так и есть. Единственное но. При первом запуске то что выдает аутлук в пути к серверу похоже на: "фыуйцйцу/////mail.asdfdasf\\\qeqwe". Хотя должен быть обычный srv-exch-st-ca.

Comment: Надеюсь не сильно введу в заблуждение, но может стоит подчистить все сетевые подключения у пользователей. мало ли куда подключались под разными учётками и теперь не пойми что куда как подключено. Диски всякие сетевые, или просто подключения к папкам из проводника. По команде net use можно просмотреть список таких подключений. Надо их всех удалить net use ... /delete.